# How to detect if python printed too many strings

Tags: python

How to detect if python printed too much?

For example, whether python printed 10 strings
or more than 10 strings?

Here is my code:

```py
def findall(directory):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for fl in files:
        path = str(os.path.join(directory,fl))
        toomuch = str(10)
        final_path = str(print(path))
        final_path = str(True)
        listdir = str(os.listdir(path))

        if listdir > toomuch:
            final_path = False
            print("Too much file to load :/")

        elif final_path == True:
            print(final_path)

        else:
            final_path = False

    return
```

How do I detect if more than 10 directories were printed?

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list of names. Check its length before printing.

Answer (score 2):

You can append each string value to an array and take the count of it. Or declare a variable with 0 value and increase it by one on each iteration, then you will get the total iteration of that loop.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, this little hack will serve your purpose.

In the solution, a global variable a `printCounter` is maintained and the `builtin` `print` function is replaced by `custom print`. In the custom print, we can add additional custom code like printing the counter value.

However, due to the uses of globals which is not thread safe, this solution should be avoided for the production code.

```
import builtins as __builtin__

# A globabl counter for the print function call
printCounter = 0 

# Override the builtin print method with custom print function
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    global printCounter
    printCounter += 1
    __builtin__.print(f'Total print so far {printCounter}') # Printing coutner
    return __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs)

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
Total print so far 1
0
Total print so far 2
1
Total print so far 3
2
Total print so far 4
3
Total print so far 5
4
```